# IOS 7 keyboard type appearance on Phonegap app

Tags: cordova, ios7

I am new to Phonegap. Working on coredova 2.8.

I have an app compiled in Xcode 5.0.2 using Base SDK IOS 7.0 and Deployment Target IOS 6.0. When I launched the app in an ios 7 device and select a TextField, I get the an ios 6 keyboard i.e. not the themed keyboard of ios 7.

However, in ios 7 simulator, it works fine.

Any help ?
Thanks

Comment: Doubt it would make a dif, but why not Xcode 5.1.1?

Comment: Try deleting the app on your device and reinstalling -- just to make sure it really does get properly cleared out and installed with your current project settings.